# Why is my Actionbar not moving up while scrolling?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with a drawer layout and a toolbar is included as follows:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    >
</include>
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer list-->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The toolbar looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:paddingTop="1dp"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

To this activity I keep on adding/replacing fragments @id/frame_container

Now I have a situation where I have a fragment with 2 tabs, which in turn have recycler views fed to a view pager:
And I am setting it up in java as follows:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout2);

    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager2);
    adapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(
            getFragmentManager(), 2);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Layout of this Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout ...
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_stacked_max_height"
    android:id="@+id/pager2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The fragments in the view pager have the recycler view.:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listViewPO"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_marginBottom="2px">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is the action bar is not hiding when I try to scroll. I am not able to figure out the issue. I have spent days with this. Please help!

Comment: Your layouts are a mess I am not surprised that it doesn't work. So you have an activity layouts with an `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar`, but you have no `CoordinatorLayout` around the `AppBarLayout`? And then in your fragment layout you actually have a `CoordinatorLayout` and an `AppBarLayout` for some reason, but this time without a `Toolbar`? What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: A few points: 1) You need a `CoordinatorLayout` around the `AppBarLayout` in your `Activity` layout, without that the `AppBarLayout` won't do anything. 2) in the `Fragment` layout remove everything but the `ViewPager`.

Comment: yep Xaver, it's a mess. I tried out a lot of combinations :(

I am trying the approach you suggested. But should I also remove the TabLayout from my fragment?

Comment: you need to add this `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your viewpager!

Comment: @XaverKapeller It worked. 
But my fragment itself is moving up along with the action bar till the same height as the action bar. 
How do I fix this?

Comment: @Panda Check out the values accepted by `app:layout_scrollFlags` at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html# - one of those comibinations will make it work as you need it to work.